# Plotting of cumulative data of multiple year in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have daily rainfall data which I have converted to yearwise cumulative value using following code

```
library(seas)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

#Loading data
data(mscdata)
dat <- (mksub(mscdata, id=1108447))
dat$julian.date <- as.numeric(format(dat$date, "%j"))
DT <- data.table(dat)
DT[, Cum.Sum := cumsum(rain), by=list(year)]

df <- cbind.data.frame(day=dat$julian.date,cumulative=DT$Cum.Sum)
```

But when I am trying to plot, it gives me weired output like

```
#Plotting using base R
df <- df[order(df[,1]),]
plot(df$day, df$cumulative, type="l", xlab="Day", ylab="Cumulative rainfall")
```

[image]

Same I am getting using `ggplot2` also like

```
#Plotting using ggplot2
ggplot(df, aes(x = day, y = cumulative)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

But I want to get lines for every year may be in grey colour and mean value over the years in red colour like the following figure

[image]

How to achieve this?

Comment: You have to add year as a group.

Comment: It worked thank you very much. For base R plotting what can be done?

Comment: Plot all as you did, but add `type="n"` and then use `lines` within each year by splitting on year,  using `lapply` or `tapply` or `split` or ...

Comment: What about adding the mean line (red one)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the group aesthetic to tell ggplot to group by the year and add `stat_summary` to draw the red line (without the grouping).

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(DT, aes(x = julian.date, y = Cum.Sum, group=year)) + 
  geom_line(col="grey") +
  labs(x="Date", y="Cumulative sum") +
  stat_summary(aes(group=NULL), fun="mean", geom="line", col="red", se="none", lwd=1)
```

[image]

For base graphics, it's a little more involved:

```
par(mar=c(4,3.5,1,1))
plot(df$day, df$cumulative, type="n", xlab="Day", ylab="Cumulative rainfall", las=1)
grid()

lapply(split(df, df$year), FUN=function(x) 
     with(x, lines(day, cumulative, col="grey", lwd=0.5)))

with(aggregate(cumulative~day, FUN=mean, data=df), 
    lines(x=day, y=cumulative, lwd=2, col="red"))
```

Comment: Excellent answer... Please visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62574268/applying-yearwise-segmented-regression-in-r), I think you will be able to answer that question also.

Answer (score 1):

So, as you can see, you lost the `group` in `geom_line`. Without `group`, `ggplot` will connect all dots sharing with the `axis.x`.
Here is an example to add 'year' as the `group` and calculate the mean value for each day.

```r
library(reshape2)

data(mscdata)
dat <- (mksub(mscdata, id=1108447))
dat$julian.date <- as.numeric(format(dat$date, "%j"))
DT <- data.table(dat)
DT[, Cum.Sum := cumsum(rain), by=list(year)]

dt <- cbind.data.frame(day=dat$julian.date,cumulative=DT$Cum.Sum,year=DT$year)
TB <- melt(dt, id.vars = c('day','year'))
Mean_l = colMeans(reshape(TB[c("day",'year','value')],timevar='day',idvar = 'year', direction = 'wide'),na.rm = T)
Mean_l= Mean_l[-1]
Mean_l <- data.frame(day=c(1:length(Mean_l)),Mean_l)

TB_f <- data.frame(TB,avr=Mean_l$Mean_l[match(TB$day,Mean_l$day)])

ggplot(TB_f,aes(day,value))+ geom_line(aes(group=year))+ geom_line(aes(y=avr),color='red')+ theme_light()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer works but it appears a bit messy which can be reduced using `tidyverse` package.