# Applying yearwise segmented regression in R

Tags: r, regression, tidyverse

I have daily rainfall data which I have converted to yearwise cumulative value using following code

```
library(seas)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

#Loading data
data(mscdata)
dat <- (mksub(mscdata, id=1108447))
dat$julian.date <- as.numeric(format(dat$date, "%j"))
DT <- data.table(dat)
DT[, Cum.Sum := cumsum(rain), by=list(year)]

df <- cbind.data.frame(day=dat$julian.date,cumulative=DT$Cum.Sum)
```

Then I want to apply segmented regression year-wise to have year-wise breakpoints. I could able to do it for single year like

```
library("segmented")
x <- subset(dat,year=="1984")$julian.date
y <- subset(DT,year=="1984")$Cum.Sum
fit.lm<-lm(y~x)
segmented(fit.lm, seg.Z = ~ x, npsi=3)
```

I have used `npsi = 3` to have 3 breakpoints. Now how to dinimically apply it year-wise segmented regression and have the estimated breakpoints?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short script to come out with a customised function so that you can run the different yearwise regressions.

```
## using tidyverse processes instead of mixing and matching with other data manipulation packages 
library(tidyverse); library(segmented); library(seas)

## get mscdata from "seas" packages
data(mscdata)
dat <- (mksub(mscdata, id=1108447))

## generate cumulative sum of rain by year
d2 <- dat %>% group_by(year) %>% mutate(rain_cs = cumsum(rain)) %>% ungroup

## write a custom function

segmentedlm <- function(data, year){
  subset.df <- data %>% filter(year == year)
  fit.lm <- lm(rain_cs ~ julian.date, subset.df)
  segmented(fit.lm, seg.Z = ~ julian.date, npsi=3)
}

# run the customised function for 1975 data
segmentedlm(d2, "1975") %>% plot(., main="1975")
```

[image]

```
segmentedlm(d2, "1984") %>% plot(., main = "1984")
```

[image]

To output the summary of segmented linear models of multiple years into a text file:

```
sink("output.txt")
lapply(c("1975", "1984"), function(x) segmentedlm(d2, x))
sink()
```

You can change the argument for lapply to input all the years.

Comment: Plotting is ok, but can it be possible to run for all the years at a time and have the breakpoints in .csv file.

Comment: what sort of output do you want on a csv file?

Comment: If you run `segmentedlm(d2, "1975")` this only, then I want to write this ```psi1.julian.date  psi2.julian.date  psi3.julian.date  
            81.5             152.0             285.7``` for all the years one below the another with row names be years.

Comment: Amended the answer above so that you can write the console output into a text file

Comment: An alternative would be using `broom::tidy` to the console output for each segmented linear model into a table. But combining them all into a single csv will be mighty confusing.

Comment: Your output is having 5 columns, but it should have 3 columns only for the three breakpoints for each year. With every run output changes, can it be fixed with `set.seed`?.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216644/discussion-between-bappa-das-and-adam-quek).

Answer (score 1):

You can store the `lm` object in a list and apply `segmented` for each `year`.

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- DT %>%
         group_by(year) %>%
         summarise(fit.lm = list(lm(Cum.Sum~julian.date)), 
                   julian.date1 = list(julian.date)) %>%
         mutate(out = map2(fit.lm, julian.date1, function(x, julian.date) 
                       data.frame(segmented::segmented(x, 
                                  seg.Z = ~julian.date, npsi=3)$psi))) %>%
         unnest_wider(out) %>%
         unnest(cols = c(Initial, Est., St.Err)) %>%
         dplyr::select(-fit.lm, -julian.date1)

# A tibble: 90 x 4
#    year Initial  Est. St.Err
#   <int>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1  1975    84.8  68.3  1.44 
# 2  1975   168.  167.   9.31 
# 3  1975   282.  281.   0.917
# 4  1976    84.8  68.3  1.44 
# 5  1976   168.  167.   9.33 
# 6  1976   282.  281.   0.913
# 7  1977    84.8  68.3  1.44 
# 8  1977   168.  167.   9.32 
# 9  1977   282.  281.   0.913
#10  1978    84.8  68.3  1.44 
# … with 80 more rows
```

Comment: How to make the list output to dataframe? Just I want to have the breakpoints (psi) as the output with year as row name. You can use `segmented(x, seg.Z = ~julian.date, npsi=3)$psi`

Comment: `segmented(fit.lm, seg.Z = ~ x, npsi=3)$psi` returns a 3 X 3 matrix so there will be 9 values. So do you want to have 9 columns?

Comment: First column is the initial breakpoint, 2nd column is the final estimate of the breakpoint and the 3rd is standard errors. If we can have the 2nd column, it will serve the purpose. All in the output will be the best with respective names.

Comment: @BappaDas but then every year would have. 3 rows right?

Comment: Yes, if you keep only the second column of the matrix.

Comment: It's the correct one but if you see the output, the Est. are same for all the years. It is not possible. I think some problem is there in the `segmented` package itself or any other problem I don't know. It was the same case with the answer of @Adam Quek also.

Comment: Yeah...I see that. I am not sure how that works. If you take output till `summarise` and store it in `data`, we can see there are different models `data$fit.lm[[1]]` , `data$fit.lm[[2]]`, but if you put them in `segmented` they generate the same output. `segmented::segmented(data$fit.lm[[1]], npsi=3)$psi` , `segmented::segmented(data$fit.lm[[2]], npsi=3)$psi`

Comment: Under such situations, what can be done? Should I accept the answer? In the meantime you can visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62129863/how-to-melt-pairwise-wilcox-test-output-using-dplyr), I think you will be able to answer it.